# javamail using "normal" provider

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Maybe it's trivial... but for me is becoming a huge waste of time because I'm not able to find the solution.

this is my code (I extrapolated first lines from very common examples on internet):

```
static Properties properties = new Properties();
{
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", getText("smtp.host"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", getText("socketFactory.port"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", getText("socketFactory.class"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", getText("smtp.auth"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", getText("smtp.port"));

    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
}

private String from = getText("from");
private String smtppw = getText("pw");

private void initMS() {
    if (smtppw != null) {
        mailsession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  new Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, smtppw);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        mailsession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, null);
            }
        });
    }   
}



String attachpath =  ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

public String sendNote(String type, SendingParamsDTO sendingParams, String filename) throws /*AddressException,*/ MessagingException {

    String res = SUCCESS;
    //try {

        if (mailsession == null) initMS();

        Message message = new MimeMessage(mailsession);

        InternetAddress pobox = new InternetAddress(from);
        InternetAddress to[] = InternetAddress.parse(sendingParams.getMailto());

        message.setFrom(pobox);
        message.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
        message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", from);
        message.setSubject("[AN-V.C.O.] - "+sendingParams.getSubject() );
        message.setSentDate( sendingParams.getDate() );

        /**/
        logger.info(" ##  FROM: "+from);
        logger.info(" ##  TO:  "+to);
        logger.info(" ##  SUBJECT:     "+sendingParams.getSubject());
        logger.info(" ##  MESSAGE:   "+sendingParams.getMessage());
        if (filename != null)
            logger.info(" ##  ATTACH:    "+attachpath + filename);
        /**/


        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        //Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        if (type.equals("text"))
            messageBodyPart1.setText(sendingParams.getMessage());
        else if (type.equals("html"))
            messageBodyPart1.setContent(sendingParams.getMessage(), "text/html");


        BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = null;
        if (filename != null){
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachpath);
            messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler( new DataHandler(source) );
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName( filename );
        }


        multipart.addBodyPart( messageBodyPart1 );
        if (filename != null){
            multipart.addBodyPart( messageBodyPart2 );
        }


        message.setContent(multipart);


        Transport.send(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        //Transport transport = mailsession.getTransport();
        //transport.connect();
        //transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        //transport.close();

    //}
    //catch(Exception e) {
    //  res = ERROR;
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //}

    return res;
}
```

where

```
## generic using GMAIL
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
socketFactory.port=465
socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
smtp.auth=true
smtp.port=465
```

and so all works fine!
Now I need to change gmail whit a commercial provider. I transformed my code in this way:

properties file becomes

```
## real using myprovider
smtp.host=smtp.myprovider.com
#socketFactory.port=465
#socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
smtp.auth=true
smtp.port=465
```

and java code

```
static Properties properties = new Properties();
{
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", getText("smtp.host"));
    //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", getText("socketFactory.port"));
    //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", getText("socketFactory.class"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", getText("smtp.auth"));
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", getText("smtp.port"));

    //properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
}
```

I tried also to keep socketfactory, to use my personal mail provider so avoiding to specify authentication and port... but still doesn't works!
what's wrong?
Thanx

PS-more specific. No error or exception is returned, only the process remains hanging executing line

```
Transport.send(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong, you should test the server if it's working. This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: First, you copied a bunch of long since obsolete and overly complicated examples.  Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Then post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing your problem.  And try the [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug) in the JavaMail FAQ.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I appreciate your suggestions. Roman, probably, indeed certainly, you're right in fact, I made new attempts trying with two new different providers and everything works like gmail. So why, about the "indicted" provider, if I use the same connection settings in Outlook (Office2010), all works fine?